# How connect one API on ODOO 12

Tags: api, odoo

Can an API be connected in ODOO?

In my country, electronic invoicing will be mandatory, the government provides an api to be able to do tests.
Where I work they want to do tests with this API but they use odoo version 12 and I wanted to know if it is possible to make that connection.

Comment: You should focus on a way more simple question. It's possible to answer your question by writing a book about Odoo and integration of APIs. What is expected of the governments API? What protocol is used? And so on...